# Access the current user id on Android

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I have a question, which is... I have a LoginActivity where the user logs in, and a DashboardActivity, if the user successfully logs in he will be redirected to the dashboard.

When I log in the json object that I get is the following:

```
{
  "id": 9,
  "email": "mario@gmail.com",
  "password": "123456"
}
```

And finally. My question is, is there a way to access the user id in the DashboardActivity?

The Stack that I am using is the following: 
Android Studio, Retrofit, GSON and Node.js.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are following ways , by which you can access the user id in Dashboard activity.

- Using bundle:
  before launching the dashboard activity you can set the value in intent as given below :

  Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
  String id= valueofId;// set value of id here.
  i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", id);

and you can retrieve this value as given below :
String userId;

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    userId = extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

- Using shared preferences:
  You can save data in loginActivity and retrive in Dashboardactivity

how to save data :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

How to get data :

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And that's it.
Happy coding!
Thank you!